# How do I update from the Fuerte Gazebo release to version 1.3

Tags: installation, gazebo-1.0, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi All,

My version of Gazebo came packaged in the Fuerte release of ROS which I believe is 1.0. How do I go about updating it to 1.3. Because in the Gazebo installation tutorials, the ROS users are told not to install from here but are instead directed back to the ROS installation page, which as far as I know only packages Gazebo 1.0?

Is there a way to upgrade gazebo without touching or changing the remainder of my ROS files?

cheers

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/761/how-do-i-update-from-the-fuerte-gazebo-release-to-version-1.3/) by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 203 on 2013-01-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've fixed the `gazebosim.org/wiki/install` instructions. You should only install Gazebo from the OSRF repository. It will not touch your ROS files, and you will still be able to use ROS with Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on 2013-01-13**:
cheers I'll give it a go

**Comment by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on 2013-01-21**:
I followed the directions but ran into issues using roslaunch. the problem has been listed here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/964/roslaunch-utilising-gazebo-10-not-gazebo-13/